# Backups for EncryptedSharedPreferences for the library are not disabled

Tags: java, android, kotlin, backup, encrypted-shared-preference

When writing my own library I encountered a problem. I have some data that I store in encryptedSP. Google documentation says that this data should not go into backup (which is why the crash occurs). According to the documentation, it is also said that we can specify the rules by which beks are formed, and indicate specific files that we do not want to save. But at the same time, this solution does not work for a library that will be pulled up by “parent” applications. As I understand it, the rules for backups are not merged and the library settings are simply overwritten and we still continue to backup data from encryptedSP. how not to backup data from encryptedSP in library?

1. Has anyone encountered this and is there a solution for this?
2. If there is a solution, what is it?
3. If there is no solution, can someone explain why this happens with excerpts from documentation or another source?

I tried to work according to the documentation - it is not the solution
There is a written crutch for this situation, in which we delete a file from encryptedSP through recursion, but this solution is extremely bad